# How to implement DI in Xamarin Forms w/o using a Service Locator pattern?

Tags: mvvm, xamarin.forms, dependency-injection, autofac, service-locator

When I do DI in MVC, I can do it without out using a service locator pattern in any of my own code. However, as I understand it, under the hood there is a service locator pattern that's already being used which I am hooking into.

So my question is, to use DI with Xamarin Forms (or MVVM in general I suppose), because there is no pre-existing service locator code which gets fired as I navigate around the application (as there is with MVC), then as best I understand it means I am going to have to do that part myself, right?

But before I go down this route, I just wanted to make sure I'm not making a mistake... that there isn't some other way to do this without having to use a service locator since there are just so many articles out there talking about how terrible this pattern is. On the one hand those articles are convincing, but on the other hand it seems to be necessary. Is it really necessary?

And please, I understand there are a million articles on why service locator is bad so I'm not looking to be further convinced of this. I'm interested whether it's even possible to avoid it, and if so how?

Comment: [Service Locator is an Anti-Pattern *by Mark Seemann*](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/)

Comment: Hi @SirRufo. I've read such articles before. Yet, under the hood, MVC implements a service locator pattern... which is the very thing that allows you to use DI w/o having to use this "anti-pattern" in your own code. Are you aware of this? If you think this could be done without a Service Locator pattern, please explain or point me to some resources explaining how to do so. Simply giving me info on why Service Locator is an anti-pattern isn't very helpful since that's the whole point of why I wrote this, lol, to find out HOW to avoid it if possible. Thanks!

Comment: I hope I don't sound too pedantic, but not all use of a DI Container is an implementation of the Service Locator anti-pattern. Mark Seemann and I have described this in more detail here [here](https://mng.bz/WaQw), where we state: "A Service Locator supplies application components *outside the Composition Root* with access to an unbounded set of Dependencies." The key here is the [Composition Root](https://mng.bz/K1qZ
) concept. Now the question becomes, how to prevent having to use the Container outside the Composition Root.

Comment: Mark and I actually wrote about UWP in [our book](https://mng.bz/BYNl) (section 7.2), but I'm unsure how these examples map to Xamarin Forms. The book's examples, however, are available online and they might still provide some insight to you. You can find the UWP example [here](https://github.com/DependencyInjection-2nd-edition/codesamples/tree/master/UWPProductManagementClient/src).

Comment: @Steven Thanks, I will check that out.

Comment: @Steven After reading your links and some other posts as well, all I can say is that I would love to see how you might implement a hello world application (or the simplest app possible that can demonstrate the principles) with an IoC container and without using a Service Locator in Xamarin Forms. Or if you have a link to such an example I would love to see it.

Comment: @Steven I'm actually seeing multiple articles explaining how to implement IoC in Xamarin by using a Service Locator One of them even readily admits it's an anti-pattern. As far as I can tell it is necessary. I would love to prove your theory true that it's not... and I have indeed been trying to, but now I'm giving up. If you ever want to take a stab at it and can show otherwise please do let me know. Thanks!